# Find the contrapositive of this lemma

Tags: real-analysis, logic

**Lemma**: If a harmonic function $h$ vanishes on two lines $L₁$ and $L₂$ and if the angle between $L₁$ and $L₂$ is not a rational multiple of $π$. Then $h$ vanishes identically.

The proof of this result can be found in: [Harmonic functions with zeros on two lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298776/harmonic-functions-with-zeros-on-two-lines)

My **question** is:

Find the contrapositive of this lemma.

I want some thing like this: The function $h$ is not vanishes identically imply that $h$ vanishes on two lines $L₁$ and $L₂$ and the angle between $L₁$ and $L₂$ is a rational multiple of $π$

Comment: my question is what have you tried?

Comment: for example after a bit researching i found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298776/harmonic-functions-with-zeros-on-two-lines

Comment: @datodatuashvili: Repeated reflections produce a dense set of lines on which the function vanishes. However, some steps are not clear.

Comment: @datodatuashvili: But there is no enought informations on that example.

Comment: maybe proof is  long  term calculation procedure or something like this

Comment: @datodatuashvili: No, it is not clear in several sides

Comment: about harmonic functions this may help you http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~boris/potential_th_notes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma is of the form

> Suppose X.  If A, then B.

There are two different statements that might be called the converse, depending on context.
First:

> Suppose X. If B, then A.

Second:

> If $B$, then $A$ and $X$.

But it seems from the question that you are actually looking for the *contrapositive*, not the converse. The converse will not negate the conclusion - in this case, the converse will assume $h$ *does* vanish identically.  In general the converse is the additional statement needed to turn an "only if" into an "if and only if".

For the contrapositive, based onthe form of the lemma, the two possibilities are

> Suppose X. If not B then not A.

and

> If not B then (not A or not X).

The first of those is more likely to be useful here. It would say

> Suppose $h$ is a harmonic function that vanishes on two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$. If $h$ does not vanish identically, then the angle between the two lines is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

By the way, the reason that there are multiple options is that the original statement (like many) is not the most simple kind of "if/then"; it has a nested structure.

Comment: @ Carl Mummert: Yes, I mean the contrapositive.

Comment: @AR1: I added some info about that